# File copy takes extra time

Tags: php, laravel-5, ftp

I am copying the files from FTP server to my local disk.

```
$allFilesList = array_filter(Storage::disk('ftp')->files('HSP'), function ($item) {
            return strpos($item, 'json');
});

foreach ($allFilesList as $file) {
            $newFile = Storage::disk('ftp')->get($file);
            Storage::disk('public')->put(basename($file),$newFile);
}

echo "finished";
```

The procedure works. The files are copied in 2-3 seconds (~ 50 files). But for some reason it takes 2-3 minutes to get through the foreach loop and display the echo. I don't know what could be causing this "delay". How could I check what is happening?

@Mark Overton
I ran the microtime. And for some reason it jumps towards the end:

```
This loop finished at 0.084124088287354
This loop finished at 0.11676001548767
This loop finished at 0.15384912490845
...
This loop finished at 1.342885017395
This loop finished at 1.3753559589386
This loop finished at 1.4076399803162
This loop finished at 181.64192605019
This loop finished at 181.67514610291
This loop finished at 181.70819401741
```

I'll add the filename to see at which file it stalled and inspect the file if it is something there. The weird part is, that I copied the last file in list way before it was rendered and the file was ok.

**Update 1**
After additional testing I found out that it always stalles at file No.40.
I moved the files to another directory to exclude hard drive problems. I tried removing the files that prevously stalled. I then tried with 39 files and that works quickly. I tried with the previously "problematic" files and without. At file No. 40 it stalles. I'll try renaming the files to see if it's a problem with filename lengths. After that I have no idea what could be the problem..

**Update 2**
After testing with different files, locations and filenames I set the timeout on the FTP connection and the result improved considerably so I'm guessing it has something to do with the driver or the FTP server itself. Anyway I will use this function once a day to copy one file. All files will be copied occasionally so I won't be optimizing any further.

The result is now:

```
Loop: 36 finished at: 1.3631699085236
Loop: 37 finished at: 1.3963389396667
Loop: 38 finished at: 1.4288220405579
Loop: 39 finished at: 1.461541891098
Loop: 40 finished at: 5.5195620059967
Loop: 41 finished at: 5.5600368976593
Loop: 42 finished at: 5.592465877533
```

Comment: When you are transferring files, you may potentially see the file name in the destination before it is actually completely transferred

Comment: I ran the code. Transferred the copied files to my local computer with filezilla. Opened the first, the last and a couple in between and they were ok. And the page was stil loading.

Comment: Is one of the files quite large or are they all around the same size? Basically as you've said, the aim is to now work-out which file is the issue and then try and work-out what could be the cause.

Comment: The files are different in size. I ran the loop twice and it stalles at the same file. This file is the average size. I ran it through my parser and found no errors with it. I'll try to move all the files to another location and change the number of files to see if there could be a problem with a total size of the files (perhaps some caching) or if there might be a problem with a hard drive...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use Microtime**

It should tell you how long each loop takes, it might be that this is just how long it takes to run, but you might find using this method a part of your code that you can speed up to get that run-time down.

```
$start = microtime(true);

$allFilesList = array_filter(Storage::disk('ftp')->files('HSP'), function ($item) {
    return strpos($item, 'json');
});

foreach ($allFilesList as $file) {

    $newFile = Storage::disk('ftp')->get($file);
    Storage::disk('public')->put(basename($file),$newFile);

    echo 'This loop finished at ' . (microtime(true) - $start) . '<br />';

}

echo "finished";
```

Comment: The files are different in size. I ran the loop twice and it stalles at the same file. This file is the average size. I ran it through my parser and found no errors with it. I'll try to move all the files to another location and change the number of files to see if there could be a problem with a total size of the files (perhaps some caching) or if there might be a problem with a hard drive...

Comment: Thanks for accepting the answer - It could also be that the file has a special or hidden character that the function doesn't like, so bare that in mind and if you struggle from this point onwards just drop me a comment on here.

Comment: Thanks for the idea on how to finf the problem. I'll check for special characters too. I added ecoes after read and after write to narrow the posibilites.

Comment: I've done the testing and the weird part is that it stalles at file No. 40 and it doesn't matter which file that is..

Comment: What happens if you split the array into two and run them in conjunction, or if you look into how much memory is being used and see if it’s hitting a cap?

Comment: I tried with 2 arrays. Te result was the same. Tried renaming the files. No change. I set the timeout to 1 second on the ftp connection. That helped. The transfer takes 7-10 seconds with the 5 seconds delay at the file No: 40 now. Which is not great but for this purpose more than enough.